# If you had a number of cubes of different sizes, what would be the algorithm to figure out the smallest cube they could fit in?

Tags: packing-problem

Is this possible to do, if so how would you do it?

"If you had a number of cubes of different sizes, what would be the algorithm to figure out the smallest cube they could fit in?"

Comment: Are we limited to integer side length?

Comment: Yes, the side lengths are integers. Thank you for the support! I am trying to figure out the algorithm in order to implement it in CS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to bin packing problems-search for that.  The simple heuristic is to sort them by size.  Put the two largest next to each other.  See if you can fit the rest into the empty space of the bounding cube.  It is likely that you can unless you have lots of little ones as the cubes increase in volume so quickly.  This is a greedy algorithm-there may be perverse cases where it fails to be optimal.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement this in Java.

Comment: Any other suggestions?